# Move Selected Email to Junk E-mail folder in Outlook using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, email, outlook, move

I'm attempting to create a sub that will simply move any currently selected mail to the default junk folder in Outlook when the sub is called.
I'm having a very hard time finding any references I can use, and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
Sub MoveItems()
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set myDestFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("youremailaddress").Folders("[Gmail]").Folders("Spam") ' or Junk
    Dim myItem As Object
    Set myItem = GetCurrentItem
    myItem.Move myDestFolder
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
    Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Case "Inspector"
    Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
    GetCurrentItem.UnRead = False
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Run Time Error '-2147221233 (8004010f)': Sorry, exchange Activesync doesn't support what you're trying to do." (I'm using Outlook 2013, by the way)

Comment: You are most likely getting this error at this line `Set myDestFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("youremailaddress").Folders("[Gmail]").Folders("Spam")`, if so make sure you have the write folder names. Please let me know

Comment: What do I replace "[Gmail]" and "MAPI" with? I replaced "youremailaddress" with my email, including the '@outlook.com', and I replaced "spam" with "spam", which is a subfolder I made of the "Inbox" folder.

Comment: You can surely get to the Junk folder the long way by walking the chain of folders. It is simpler for default folders.  Set myDestFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861868%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Based on your description please try `Set myDestFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Spam")`

Comment: The code looks like it should be working, but no matter what I try, I still get the error message mentioned above. The only "solution" I can find is people saying to downgrade to Outlook 2010, which is hardly ideal. This makes no sense; why would I get an error message saying Activesync can't move an email to another folder? I'm able to do it manually.

Comment: What line of code causes the error? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: If a folder's name was incorrect, wouldn't I get an "object not found" error?  When the error comes up, it doesn't indicate what line is causing the error, but it seems to occur whenever I'm trying to use the 'MailItem.Move method. I take it no one else can replicate the problem?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4e6f660d-fe2a-426b-9506-19f6bf2816dc/cannot-movecopy-messages-from-pst-to-activesync-hotmail-folder?forum=outlook it appears that this is a bug with Outlook 2013. Several workarounds are proposed. I don't get this problem because I use gmail :).

Comment: Macros not being able to move mail to another folder seems to be a pretty big design flaw. Because I'm not attempting to sync my emails between multiple accounts, Activesync seems like it shouldn't even effect me. Oh well, I guess I'll be rolling back to Outlook 2010. Thanks for your time and help everyone.

Comment: I'm replying again to say that the above code works flawlessly on Outlook 2010, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My version of macros:

```
Public Sub MarkSelectedAsSpam()
    Dim junkFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set junkFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
    Dim email As Object
    For Each email In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        email.Move junkFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Removes selected emails to junk folder.