Forward an Outlook email but from the original sender, not my email address
Is it possible to forward or copy an email to a different address but make it come from the original sender, not my own Outlook address. This would be done in VBA Outlook (desktop).
So if abc@gmail.com sends a mail to me, I want it to be forwarded to xyz@gmail.com, as if abc@gmail.com had sent it.
Please see my attempt below. It goes into my outbox as if from the original sender, but once sent, it looks like it came from me, and a reply would come to me.
Sub SendEmail(objMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    Dim originalSender As String

    On Error GoTo Release
    
    If objMail.Class = olMail Then
        ' Forward the original email instead of creating a new mail item
        Set oMail = objMail.Forward
        oMail.Subject = objMail.Subject
        oMail.Recipients.Add "sendtothisaddress@email.com"
        
        ' Preserve the original sender information
        originalSender = "<p><b>Original Sender:</b> " & objMail.SenderName & " (" & objMail.SenderEmailAddress & ")</p><br><br>"
        oMail.HTMLBody = originalSender & objMail.HTMLBody
        
        ' Attempt to send on behalf of the original sender
        oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
        
        ' Send the email
        oMail.Send
    End If

Release:
    Set oMail = Nothing
End Sub


I don't think that Office will allow you to impersonate another email address.  There are a massive number of ways that kind of functionality can be abused for malicious purposes.

Is your goal for the receiver to reply to the original sender?

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571407/niton yes that is correct, and also for a shared mailbox (all_relevant_incoming_forwarded_mail) to show the original sender in the Inbox, so you can quickly see who it's originally from

Reference the destination folder. See the idea here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851850/outlook-selecting-a-subfolder-in-the-sharedmailbox-using-getshareddefaultfolder. Then .Move or .Copy the item https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594107/move-selected-email-to-junk-e-mail-folder-in-outlook-using-vba-macro

Outlook Object Model (or Extended MAPI) won't let you do it to avoid spoofing. On the Exchange Server level, a rule can be created that forwards incoming messages while preserving the original server.
In OOM, you can try to create olRuleActionRedirect rule, but if I remember correctly, it always gets converted to a client-side rule, so it does not preserve the sender.
I don't think there is any way to do that without Extended MAPI (you'd need to set FWD_PRESERVE_SENDER /FWD_DO_NOT_MUNGE_MSG bits in the ulActionFlavor for the OP_FORWARD action flavor). Extended MAPI can only be used from C++ or Delphi. If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, it too exposes olRuleActionRedirect rule that works correctly in Exchange.
